# How to combine a column of lists into single values

Tags: python

This may be a simple tasks but I have having difficulties finding a solution. I have a single column data frame of lists. For example the first three lists in my column are as follows:
`0: [100.0, 90.8, 74.0, 16.0] 1: [98.0, 87.84, 54.0, 10.0] 2: [95.0, 85.18, 50.0, 8.0]`
I have 10,000 rows of similar lists. I to create a column of the values like this:

```
0: 1009087416 1: 9887845410 2: 958518508
```

and so on.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you mean a panda dataframe or just a python list?

Comment: You need to post a sample of your actual dataframe, this is way too ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Dataframe!
The simple way, in this case, you can be used like this. I think it is not the best way, but it simple.

```
def combine_data(data):
   # do combine your column here

df[colname] = df[colname].apply(lambda row: combine_data(row.colname), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Still learning myself,
although I know its not the best thing to be looping through a dataframe,
especially since you mentioned 10,000 rows,
but is this what you were after? Or at least point you in the right direction...

```
def convertToStr(value):
  s = str(value)
  return(s.replace(".0","").replace(".",""))

df = pd.DataFrame({'0':[100.0, 90.8, 74.0, 16.0],'1': [98.0, 87.84, 54.0, 10.0],'2': [95.0, 85.18, 50.0, 8.0]})
ColumnValues = {}

numberOfColumns = len(df.columns)
for i in range(numberOfColumns):
  tmp = ""
  columnList = df.iloc[:,i]
  for value in columnList:
    tmp = tmp + convertToStr(value)
  ColumnValues[i] = tmp

print(ColumnValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the structure is not clear, I'm assuming two structures. *(Refer to comments in code for help)*

If your dataset is,

```
                           0
0  [100.0, 90.8, 74.0, 16.0]
1  [98.0, 87.84, 54.0, 10.0]
2   [95.0, 85.18, 50.0, 8.0]
```

The following code,

```
import pandas as pd

lst = ['[100.0, 90.8, 74.0, 16.0]', '[98.0, 87.84, 54.0, 10.0]', '[95.0, 85.18, 50.0, 8.0]']

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    convertedstring = (" ".join(map(str, eval(row[0])))) #convert row[0] to list object and use join to convert to string
    cleanedstring = convertedstring.replace(".0", " ").replace(".", " ").replace(" ", "")  #remove .0 first for differentiation, remove , & remove spaces
    df = df.replace(row[0],cleanedstring)

print(df)
```

Gives you,

```
            0
0  1009087416
1  9887845410
2   958518508
```

OR if your data structure is the following,

```
                                                   0
0  0: [100.0, 90.8, 74.0, 16.0] 1: [98.0, 87.84, ...
```

Then the following code,

```
import pandas as pd

lst = ['0: [100.0, 90.8, 74.0, 16.0] 1: [98.0, 87.84, 54.0, 10.0] 2: [95.0, 85.18, 50.0, 8.0]']

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df)

d = "]"    #stated delimiter
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    s =  [e+d for e in row[0].split(d) if e]  #split by ] without removing delimiter
    count = 0
    fullstring = ''
    for items in s:
        convertedstring = (" ".join(map(str, eval((items.split(':'))[1]))))    #same as previous
        cleanedstring = convertedstring.replace(".0", " ").replace(".", " ").replace(" ", "")     #same as previous
        fullstring += str(count) + ": " + cleanedstring + " "    #reconstruct the string and save
        count += 1
    df = df.replace(row[0],fullstring)

print(df)
```

Gives you,

```
                                           0
0  0: 1009087416 1: 9887845410 2: 958518508
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the DataFrame as below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'0': [100.0, 90.8, 74.0],
                   '1': [98.0, 87.84, 54.0],
                   '2': [95.0, 85.18, 50.0]})
print(df)

# result as below:
       0      1      2
0  100.0  98.00  95.00
1   90.8  87.84  85.18
2   74.0  54.00  50.00
```

Result:

```py
            0           1           2
0  1000908740  9808784540  9508518500
```

Step by step:

```py
LIST = []
for col in df.columns.tolist():
    a = df[col].values.astype(str).tolist()
    LIST.append(''.join(a))
# LIST : 
> ['100.090.874.0', '98.087.8454.0', '95.085.1850.0']

new_array = np.array(LIST).reshape(1, -1)
# convert 1d list to 2d array. 
> [['100.090.874.0' '98.087.8454.0' '95.085.1850.0']]

dfnew = pd.DataFrame(new_array)
>                0              1              2
> 0  100.090.874.0  98.087.8454.0  95.085.1850.0

dfnew.replace('\.', '', regex=True)
# replace dot
>             0           1           2
> 0  1000908740  9808784540  9508518500
```